# Setting up WinMain from other .cpp?

Tags: c++, windows, function

I am trying to experiment little with c++ but i have some problems now...

Basicaly what i want is in my main.cpp there is a WinMain function and inside it there is nothing cus i placed all that should be inside it into another file (window.cpp) and i want the WinMain function in main.cpp to call the window in window.cpp or in some way make it equal the window.cpp..

Here is main.cpp

```
    #include <windows.h>

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpszArgument,int nFunsterStil)
{

}
```

And here is window.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "WindowsApp";

int WINAPI window (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nFunsterStil)

{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Windows App",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I realy have no idea how i would do this, Please some help

Comment: Just put the prototype for the functions in `windows.cpp` in a header and include that in your main file.

Comment: Could you maybe explain little more please?

Comment: Please read C or C++ tutorials or reference guides. You are already doing what you need to do by including `windows.h` and calling winapi functions. Think about it.

Comment: Yes but int the main.cpp in the WinMain thats were the program starts.. And now it does nothing.. I want it to do what it says in window.cpp.. I realy need maybe to look up a guide or tutorial how headers work..

Comment: In your `window` function, you call RegisterClassEx. That function is not defined in your C++ file. Why does that work? Do exactly the same thing for your own code.

Comment: Am realy getting confused.. RegisterClassEX is not defined in my C++ file?? both of the files are mine.. and it is defined.. And why does what work?, And what own code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WinMain` doesn't need to be in "main.cpp" -- you can put it in any file.  Just rename `window` to `WinMain` and you'll be done.

Comment: You don't call WinMain() explicitly - It's the entry point function of your program that gets called automatically by the CRT loader during execution.